# Issue about logical output from MEX function in MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

Why is the output always 1 from my MEX function although it was expected to be 0?

I wrote the following MEX source code shown below

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
  bool *x,*y;

  /* Create matrix for the return argument. */
  plhs[0] = mxCreateLogicalMatrix(1,1);

  /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
  x = mxGetLogicals(prhs[0]); //input
  y = mxGetLogicals(plhs[0]); //output

  /* Calculations. */
  if (*x == 0) *y = 1;
  else *y = 0;
}
```

and the following appears:

```
y = test(5)

y =

     1
```

Comment: So did my answer help?

Comment: Yes Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to point you to the documentation of [`mxGetLogicals`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetlogicals.html).  Part of the documentation says:

> *Returns*
>
> Pointer to the first logical element in the `mxArray`. The result is **unspecified** if the `mxArray` is not a logical array.

What you are passing is a `double` precision number, **not** a `logical`.  By doing this, you will get undefined behaviour. As such, there are three ways you can resolve this error:

1. Pass an actual `logical` value to the function.
2. Leave everything as is, but change what you are returning.  Instead of `*y = 1` and `*y = 0`, change this to `true` and `false` respectively, but the input has to be `double`.
3. You basically must change any reference to `logical / bool` to `double`.  Specifically, change `mxGetLogicals` to [`mxGetPr`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetpr.html) so you can get a pointer to a `double` precision real array.  You'll also need to change `mxCreateLogicalMatrix` to [`mxCreateDoubleMatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxcreatedoublematrix.html) and you'll have to change your pointers from `bool` to `double`.

## Option #1 - Passing a `logical` value to the function:

You simply need to do:

```
y = test(false);
```

or:

```
y = test(true);
```

---

Running this with these changes gives me the following:

```
>> y = test(false)

y =

     1

>> y = test(true)

y =

     0
```

## Option #2 - Input type is `double`, output type is `bool`:

These changes are what you need to make:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
  double *x;
  bool *y; // Change

  /* Create matrix for the return argument. */
  plhs[0] = mxCreateLogicalMatrix(1,1);

  /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
  x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //input - Change
  y = mxGetLogicals(plhs[0]); //output

  /* Calculations. */
  if (*x == 0) *y = true; // Change
  else *y = false;
}
```

---

---

Running this code with the above changes gives me:

```
>> y = test(0)

y =

     1

>> y = test(5)

y =

     0
```

## Option #3 - Change `bool` behaviour to `double`:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[] )
{
  double *x,*y; // Change

  /* Create matrix for the return argument. */
  plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,1,mxREAL); // Change

  /* Assign pointers to each input and output. */
  x = mxGetPr(prhs[0]); //input - Change
  y = mxGetPr(plhs[0]); //output - Change

  /* Calculations. */
  if (*x == 0) *y = 1;
  else *y = 0;
}
```

---

Running this code with the above changes gives me:

```
>> y = test(0)

y =

     1

>> y = test(5)

y =

     0
```

Comment: Isn't it also possible to change the function to accept a double input but still output a logical?

Comment: @aschepler yes it is. I just didn't think of it. I'll add that other option in.